# Can I run a command loaded from .bashrc with sudo?

Tags: bash, sudo, bashrc

I have some custom functions and aliases defined in my `.bashrc` file. Sometimes I need to execute whem as root. I then do something like:

```
$ sudo custom_cmd 80                                                                                                                                   
sudo: custom_cmd: command not found
```

How can I execute such commands with root privileges?

EDIT: Of course to achieve that I could simply source my `.bashrc` as root but I want to know if there is some quick (in terms of typing needed) way to do this. I also would like to avoid any customization if that is possible (such as sourcing my `.bashrc` automatically).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run it through your shell:

```
sudo bash -c 'source /home/reachus/.bashrc; custom_cmd 80'
```

Alternatively, write a script which sources `.bashrc` for you, say `/usr/local/bin/my`:

```
#! /bin/bash
source /home/reachus/.bashrc
"$@"
```

Then do:

```
sudo my custom_cmd 80
```

Comment: Yes, I can obviously source my `.bashrc` file but I am looking for more quicker solution. I'll edit my question.

Comment: @REACHUS write a script which does the same thing: `source .bashrc; "$0" "$@"`.

Comment: You're right, that should be enough.

Comment: @REACHUS argh, I mean: simply `"$@"`, since `$0` would be the script name.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem.

You can also

```
  cd /etc/profile.d
  sudo gedit ./newfile.sh (you write commands here, can be nano also)
  sudo chmod +x newfile.sh
```

It should run automatically whenever you login to your account. 
To test it, instead of restarting, just run "su yourusername" in bash and login and it should work.