# "command not found" when sudo'ing function from ~/.zshrc

Tags: sudo, zsh

I have a function in my `~/.zshrc`:

```
findPort() {
    lsof -t -i :$1
}
```

The usual invocation is `findPort 3306`.

I want to run it with elevated privileges. But I get "command not found".

```
➜  git  sudo findPort 3306
sudo: findPort: command not found
```

I presume the reason is that the root user either runs as a non-interactive shell (thus does not refer to a .zshrc), or refers to a *different* `.zshrc`.

I have seen similar questions regarding `alias`, but no question regarding user-defined functions. The answers for this problem regarding `alias` involves adding an alias to `~/.zshrc`:

```
alias sudo='nocorrect sudo '
```

Or perhaps:

```
alias sudo='sudo '
```

I have tried both of these solutions, and the problem still exists (yes I've relaunched the shell).

I have also tried running `sudo chsh` to ensure that my root shell runs under `zsh`. None of these solutions removes the "command not found" problem.

Is there a way to run my user-defined functions under sudo?

Comment: Also see: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181414/can-i-run-a-command-loaded-from-bashrc-with-sudo/ (not flagging because zsh has its own tricks)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`sudo` runs commands directly, not via a shell, and even if it ran a shell to run that command, it would be a new shell invocation, and not one that reads your `~/.zshrc` (even if it started an interactive shell, it would probably read `root`'s `~/.zshrc`, not yours unless you've configured `sudo` to not reset the `$HOME` variable).

Here, you'd need to tell `sudo` to start a new `zsh` shell, and tell that `zsh` to read your `~/.zshrc` before running that function:

```
sudo zsh -c '. $0; "$@"' ~/.zshrc findPort 3306
```

Or:

```
sudo zsh -c '. $0; findPort 3306' ~/.zshrc
```

Or to share your current zsh functions with the new `zsh` invoked by `sudo`:

```
sudo zsh -c "$(functions); findPort 3306"
```

Though you might get an *arg list too long* error if you have a lot of functions defined (like when using the completion system). So you may want to limit it to the `findPort` function (and every other function it relies on if any):

```
sudo zsh -c "$(functions findPort); findPort 3306"
```

You could also do:

```
sudo zsh -c "(){$functions[findPort]} 3306"
```

To embed the code of the `findPort` function in an *anonymous function* to which you pass the 3306 argument. Or even:

```
sudo zsh -c "$functions[findPort]" findPort 3306
```

(the inline script passed to `-c` *is* the body of the function).

You could use a helper function like:

```
zsudo() sudo zsh -c "$functions[$1]" "$@"
```

Do not use:

```
sdo() { sudo zsh -c "(){$functions[$1]} ${@:2}" }
```

As the arguments of `sdo` would undergo another level of shell parsing. Compare:

```
$ e() echo "$@"
$ sdo e 'tname;uname'
tname
Linux
$ zsudo e 'tname;uname'
tname;uname
```

Comment: I need a solution that's as short as typing `sudo`. I was able to adapt your _anonymous function_ solution to do just that. I have added the following function to my `~/.zshrc`, which is a function to run _other functions_ with elevated privileges: `sdo() { sudo zsh -c "(){$functions[$1]} ${@:2}" }`

Comment: @Birchlabs, see edit

Comment: Thanks; I've updated my answer to use the newer shortcut you've proposed.

Comment: Adding the function definition to the script executed through sudo is smart. But not smart enough if that function use another function (autoloaded or not).

Answer (score 4):

A very simple solution for me was to invoke an interactive shell using `sudo -s`, which appears to work on my macOS bundled version of zsh (5.2). This provides me with the functions from my `~/.zshrc`.

From the sudo manpage, which doesn't really hint at this behaviour:

> -s, --shell
>   Run the shell specified by the SHELL environment variable if it is set or the shell specified by the invoking user's password database entry.  If a command is
>   specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.

I'm not sure what your use case is, but I suspect you're looking for an interactive solution.

Comment: This does indeed work. Though it's not quite the workflow I had in mind. My desire is to remain in a prompt as my usual user, and elevate just my user-defined function `myFunc`, by typing `sudo myFunc` — the same way I would elevate _any_ process (like `sudo rm -rf .`). This solution elevates my entire prompt and all future functions, as well as changing my user for all future functions — which is a bit overkill.

Comment: The `sudo -s` command will launch another instance of your shell as the superuser. If you execute that command interactively, your new shell will be interactive. But the command `sudo -s findPort 3306` will run the command `findPort 3306` in your shell as the superuser then exit with the status code of that command.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to produce a reusable *shorthand* for one of the solutions described in Stéphane Chazelas' [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317689/191304).
[Edit: Stéphane has iterated on the original shortcut I proposed; the code described here is a newer version, of his making]

Put this into your `~/.zshrc`:

```bsh
sdo() sudo zsh -c "$functions[$1]" "$@"
```

Now you can use `sdo` as a "`sudo` for user-defined functions only".

To confirm that `sdo` works: you can try it out on a user-defined function that prints your username.

```bsh
➜ birch@server ~/  test() whoami

➜ birch@server ~/  test
birch

➜ birch@server ~/  sdo test
root
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work for me:

```
function sudo (){
  args="$@"
  /run/wrappers/bin/sudo -u "$USER" zsh -i -c "$args"
}
```